# Jquery Page Scrolling Animation Framework

Tags: jquery, single-page-application

I look for best jQuery library/framework to create 'One Page Scroll' website.

And just could find small plugins and some tutorials, that's not stable or doesn't support maintenance.

Is there any powerful jQuery library to create animate page scroll which considers facilities such as:

1. Existing Documents/Tutorials/Examples and API references
2. I would like it has so many options to handling different kind of effects like (Navigation scrollto : true/false; auto fix section position: true/false; Scroll continuing/Section by section (stop on new section) Keyboard:true/false :Mouse: false/true; Scrollbar: true/false; ...)
3. Active Support
4. All browser support
5. Responsive
6. Support mobile and tablet device (Support touchscreen)
7. Using other jQuery Animation framework (Like TweenJs) inside sections

Comment: Check out some of them here http://bit.ly/1mnfs7N

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you are looking for [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).
It fits all your requirements I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Check this library can help you or not!
http://lvming6816077.github.io/H5FullscreenPage/